# Get the location of object to crop by providing pixel label in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a data-set of images(every image is in rgb format) and corresponding label image(which contains label of every pixel in the image). 
I need to extract the objects(pixels) of a particular class from original images.

first i have to find location of object using label image(by providing label of given object)(it is doable by using explicit for loops but, i don't want to use explicit for loops)

Now my questions-

If there is any in-build function in tensorflow that gives me the location(Rectangles are fine) of given object(if i provide the labels of that object)?

After that i can use the tf.image.crop_and_resize to crop the image. but i am not able to find any function that will give me location of objects.